# How do convert an array to an object in PostgreSQL with data like this?

Tags: json, postgresql

```
[{name:'a',test :1},{name:'b',test :2}]
```

to

```
{ a : {test:1}, b:{test:2} }
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is valid JSON, you can use the built-in [functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) and [aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT json_object_agg(a.e ->> 'name', a.e - 'name')
FROM jsonb_array_elements('[{"name":"a","test":1},{"name":"b","test":2}]') a(e)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pR9Jqcyb)

Comment: Or just: `SELECT json_object_agg(a.e ->> 'name', a.e - 'name')
FROM   jsonb_array_elements('[{"name":"a","test":1},{"name":"b","test":2}]') a(e)`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'm always struggling with set-returning functions. Thanks for the improvement!